# C: How to extend variable-length strings to set length

Tags: c, string

How do I fill a string with enough `0`'s (from the beginning) to make it 5 characters long if it is less than that initially?

eg `100` --> `00100`

Comment: One approach is writing a code that fills a string with enough 0's to make it 5 characters long if it's less than that initially.

Comment: Why don't you use `sprintf`'s formatting option to put leading zeroes into the string when you're creating it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Some Code

```
char s[10];
snprintf(s, 10, "%05d", 100);
```

#### Which results in

```
s contains "00100"
```